# How to mark a point (I have x,y,z for it) in a 3D big data scatter plot with different color using matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter3d

I have two 3D volume images and I want to locate one point from the first image (I have specific x, y, and z values for this point) and mark it with a different color. I mean how I can insert the values of x, y, and z and get this point in my graph inside all the points with a different color.

Comment: Have you tried 'hold on', and then just plot that individual point with whatever specified color you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 options:

**Option 1**

Use `hold` to overlay another scatter only with the points you want to color differently:

```
data = rand(100,3); % some data
p = randi(100); % choose some point
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),'Fill')
hold on
% here you plot only one point (p):
scatter3(data(p,1),data(p,2),data(p,3),'r','Fill')
hold off
```

[image]

**Option 2**

If you want to color more than one point, and/or use different colors for your points, it may be better to set the color by the point when you call `scatter` in the first time:

```
data = rand(100,3); % some data
p = randi(size(data,1),5,1); % choose some points
c = ones(size(data,1),1); % default color
c(p) = 2:(numel(p)+1); % set different color for each points in p
col = lines(numel(p)+1); % set the colormap for the points
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),[],col(c,:),'Fill')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using scatter3, you can just make your scatterplot, then use "hold on" and add a scatterplot with your single point in a different color that will cover the original point, e.g.:

```
hold on; 
scatter3(x,y,z,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor',[0 .75 .75]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated